# What is the c# equivalent of "Map<Integer, List<String>> propName;" please?

Tags: c#, json

How do I declare `Map<Integer, List<String>> propName` in my c# web client please so that it will unparse a json string/class that looks like

```
"propName" : {3: ["userId", "email"]}
```

I did google this before asking here but didn't find an answer specific to what looks like a complex type that the web api guy sent me below. I don't recognise the `Map<,>` data struct he's using.

```
public class ErrorObject
{
   int error;
   string errorText;
   string hint;
   Map<Integer, List<String>> propName; // e.g. "propName" : {3: ["userId", "email"]}
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using here to deserialize your info's? I guess you could do it with `Dictionary<string,object>`

Comment: If you have the JSON already and are unsure what to create to deserialize it to, [there are tools](http://json2csharp.com/) that can help.

Comment: `IDictionary<int, IList<string>>` is the closest equivalent. Be aware that you can't add null keys into a `Dictionary<K, V>` however.

Comment: var deSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ErrorObject));
          result = (ErrorObject)deSer.ReadObject(tr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```
public class ErrorObject
{
    int error;
    String errorText;
    String hint;
    Dictionary<int, List<String>> propName;
}
```

But you can also simply paste your full JSON to [this converter](http://json2csharp.com) and it will give you the matching class structure in C#.

Comment: Thanks :D Re the converter. The json responses I've been receiving havent contained that last field so far. The dev told me about the structure of the response when I queried the structure of the class (it wasnt in the old api documents I have) and I was surprised to see the final field as I'd not seen it in any response I'd received. Im in process of writing code to see if I get an error when expecting that data but not receiving it